# Use variable storing key from dict1 as new key for dict2

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I want to pull keys and their values from a dictionary that meet conditions, then store them in another dictionary. What I thought of so far was:

```
dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
new_dict = {}
for x in dict:
    new_dict.update(x=dict[x])
print (dict)
print (new_dict)
```

Here, `x` stores a key `'a'` with value `1`, but when I update `new_dict`, it stores `x: 2`, meaning during the first loop it created a new key `x` and reinitialized the key during the second loop. It means that Python is interpreting `x` as a literal.

Is there anyway to have `new_dict` store `'a': 1` and `'b': 2`?

Comment: that's a duplicate. I want to copy, for example, only ```a``` over. I hope to iterate through ```dict``` and keys that fit a condition are then stored into ```new_dict```.

Comment: For starters, the whole point of `update` is to do: `new_dict.update(old_dict)`. To assign *a single item*, use `new_dict[some_key] = some_value`, if you *really* must use `update` (you don't) then you can do the overwrought `new_dict.update({some_key:some_value})` or even more overwrought `new_dict.update([(some_key, some_value)])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 27 2018, 07:35:06) 
>>> d1 = {'a':1,'b':2}
>>> d2 = {}
>>> for k,v in d1.items():
...     if True:
...             d2[k] = v
... 
>>> d2
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

You would just replace `if True` with your condition.

See here for some more info on looping over dictionaries: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques